# How to test views in Django?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I try to create test to my views in django app, in my `setUp` method i want to create new object and then pass `id` of this object to `reverse('edit')` to test passing an id like I have in my `urls`, here is code:

test_views.py

```
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.edit = reverse('edit', args=['id'])
        self.id = Employee.objects.create(
            econtact='testContact',
            eemail='test@tset.pl',
            ename='testName'
        ).id
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('edit/<int:id>', views.edit, name="edit"),
]
```

model

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    ename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    eemail = models.EmailField()
    econtact = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

can somone tell me why, after run this test case, my console throw me:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'edit' with arguments '('id',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$']
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The `args=['id']` in `reverse` does not make much sense, since that would mean you have a URL where the string `'id'` is the primary key, not an `int` that is stored in a variable named `id`.

You thus should setup the test with:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.client = Client()
    self.id = Employee.objects.create(
        econtact='testContact',
        eemail='test@tset.pl',
        ename='testName'
    ).id
    self.edit = reverse('edit', args=[self.id])
```

Comment: I try and compiler throw: `location = "django_testid://" + str(test.id())
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Comment: `test.id()` makes no sense, it is `test.id`..., thus `location = f'django_testid://{ test.id }'`.

Comment: test still fail, i think that problem is with `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Comment: because this `str(test.id())` is from internal python function

Comment: @methodinvocation: please edit the question with the *full* traceback.